# ASP.NET Identity Two Factor not working - Cookie Issue?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

**Background:**

I have been using the `Identity-Sample` project provided by the Microsoft team [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity#SMS):

I have integrated the `Identity-Sample` project & prerelease nuget packages into an existing project, that was previously using the latest stable version of Identity.

**Problem:**

When trying 2FA, inside the `Account/SendCode` method, there is a call to `GetVerifiedUserIdAsync()`  , which is part of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`  class. (see the [full code here](https://github.com/hylander0/MasterKeyAuthentication/blob/master/MasterKey/Identity/SignInHelper.cs#L59))

**`GetVerifiedUserIdAsync()` is returning null** (i.e. it could not find a verified user, even though I have logged in with 1 factor.) **I believe that it is not finding the correct cookie.**

When I run the `Identity-Sample` app, my browser shows a `_RequestVerificationToken` AND `TwoFactorCookie` & everything works.

When I run my own app, my browser shows ONLY the `_RequestVerificationToken` cookie & I get `null`.

**Question: (if the cookie is the issue)**

How can I get my app to correctly set the cookie when the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)` method is called (inside `Account/Login`)?

Comment: I'm confused.  `GetVerfiedUserIdAsync()` *SHOULD* return null if you haven't verified your user (you say you have only done 1 factor), so what is the problem?

Comment: thanks for taking a look -- I believe GetVerifiedUserIdAsync() should provide the userId (User.Identity.GetUserId()) when signed in with 1 factor. That's what it seems to do in the sample app provided by the Microsoft team...

Comment: so to clarify, still looking for an answer, if anyone has insights...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Startup.Auth class register the cookie

```
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

In the Login page post action, if you use the new SigninManager.PasswordSigninAsync, it will set the intermittent cookie if 2 FA is enabled on the user and return SignInStatus.RequiresVerification. You can then use SigninManager.GetVerifiedUserAsync should return the user ID

Comment: 1> I have called SigninManager.PasswordSigninAsync; 2> I am receiving SignInStatus.RequiresVerification. 3> But I am getting null When I am calling await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync(); what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem as @TazbirBhuiyan. I got it to work a few times, but it stopped.

Comment: I was having this problem and it was because I was calling SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync() in the same request as the username/password POST which is before the cookie had been set. If you need the UserId at this point you can use _userManager.FindByEmailAsync() and pass in the username then use the response to get the Id of the User.

Comment: You are awesome! You saved me a lot of time. Thanks.